# Use two lists as input to Spatial Join in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-join, list

I am trying to determine a method for conducting a spatial join on features from two separate feature datasets based on the first three letters of each input feature (A01_road == A01_gps).

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = r'E:\GPS\GPS.gdb'

rds = r'E:\Pathways_GPS\Pathways.gdb\road_lines'
wlk_pts = r'E:\Pathways_GPS\Pathways.gdb\Walking_points'
output = r'E:\Pathways_GPS\Pathways.gdb\road_join'

#Spatial Join Variables 
join_operation = 'JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE'
join_type = 'KEEP_COMMON'
field_mapping = ''
match_option = 'WITHIN_A_DISTANCE'
search_radius = '15 meter'
name_suffix = "_400join"

arcpy.env.workspace = rds
road_list = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for road in road_list:
    road_fc = road[:3]
    arcpy.env.workspace = wlk_pts
    walk_list = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    for walk in walk_list:
        walk_fc=walk[:3]
        if road_fc == walk_fc:
            out_fc = (os.path.join(output,(join_fc [:3]+ name_suffix)))
            arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(target_fc,join_fc, out_fc, join_operation, join_type, '', match_option, search_radius,'')
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Comment: for each A01_road, is there only one A01_gps? it might be easier to do it with a dictionary and update cursor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Because you have defined full path for output, you don't need `arcpy.env.workspace` for it.
- I assume you want to join `walk_points` to `road_lines`.
- You can define `walk_list` outside the loop, it's just string list.

```py
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#Spatial Join Variables 
join_operation = 'JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE'
join_type = 'KEEP_COMMON'
field_mapping = ''
match_option = 'WITHIN_A_DISTANCE'
search_radius = '15 meter'
name_suffix = "_400join"

# Feature datasets
rds = r'E:\Pathways_GPS\Pathways.gdb\road_lines'
wlk_pts = r'E:\Pathways_GPS\Pathways.gdb\Walking_points'
output = r'E:\Pathways_GPS\Pathways.gdb\road_join'

# FeatureClass lists
arcpy.env.workspace = rds
road_list = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()  
arcpy.env.workspace = wlk_pts
walk_list = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for road in road_list:
    road_fc = (os.path.join(rds, road))
    for walk in walk_list:
        if road[:3] == walk[:3]:            
            walk_fc = (os.path.join(wlk_pts, walk))
            out_fc  = (os.path.join(output, (road + walk[3:] + name_suffix)))
            arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(road_fc, walk_fc, out_fc, join_operation, join_type, '', match_option, search_radius, '')
```

[image]